# Wrong use of state condition

Tags: c

I am using the following code to check if bit number 25 value is 0 or 1:

```
volatile unsigned int * regAddr;
unsigned int regval;

regAddress = (unsigned int *) 0xD2009010;   //This is a valid address of register

regVal = *regAddress;   //The return value here is 0xFE008000

if (!(regVal & 0x4000000))     //For the mentioned return value, I thought the condition will be different then 0 and so used '!' to convert the value
    the bit is 0;
else
    the bit is 1;
```

This code isn't working properly and I cannot figure out why. Help anyone? Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you expect and what is it doing?

Comment: And first of all, what platform? I wouldn't expect magic constants to point to valid memory...

Comment: Doesn't do anything. what is regAddress? And regAddr not used anywhere.

Comment: I suspect that `regAddress` is a typo since your declaration is `regAddr`??

Comment: @Jite: exactly but I lose interest when the code doesn't even compile - OP hasn't tested it.

Comment: It sounds good. Any example where it's not working ?

Comment: Are you sure `0x4000000` is testing the `25th` bit? I think you need `0x1000000`.

Comment: @Bathsheba The question was ofcourse meant for user2568434 :) No and it will most likely not work on your machine either with magic memory addresses :)

Comment: @abelenky We already mentioned that twice. The problem is as Shafik Yaghmour says, he isn't testing bit 25. He is testing bit 26 (or 27) depending on if you start with the first bit as index 0 or 1.

Comment: @user2568434:  Why do you keep changing the names of your variables?  Your last edit changed `regAddress` back to `regAddr`.  Do you not understand the importance of proper variable names??

Answer (score 5):

The sure-way to get the 25th bit is:

```
if (!(regVal & (1 << 24) ))
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
#define BIT_25 (1 << 24)  // the first-bit, shifted over 24 more times.

if (!(regVal & BIT_25 ))
```

---

Several people raise the point that "bit number 25" is ambiguous, depending on if you consider 0x01 to be the first-bit, or the zeroth-bit.
Decide this yourself as is appropriate for your program.
But no matter what, `0x4000000` is not right.

Comment: Your code is right to change the twenty-fifth bit. Only unclear was if the author wanted to change bit at index 25 or the 25th bit.

Comment: I changed the code accordingly, but the issue continue. I checked to Assembly code created, it seems the compiler is using LSL R1, R1, #6 in order to move bit number 25 to MSB position, and then checks if the number is positive or not. from some reason, although the MSB is now 1 (for the example above), the CPU handles it as 0. VERY STRANGE

Comment: Please recognize that in your original question you stated, *"This code isn't working properly"* and now you state *"the issue continue"*.  Yet you do not say what is actually happening!  You should include the *exact* value of `regVal`, and a **full** description of what you expect should happen.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at shift operators:

http://www-numi.fnal.gov/offline_software/srt_public_context/WebDocs/Companion/cxx_crib/shift.html

Something like

```
if ((yourVal >> 25) & 0x1)
```

Should do what you want.

For example: Printing the whole number then the 25th and 26th bits:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int     getBitValue(unsigned int num, unsigned int pos) {
  return ((num >> pos) & 0x1);
}

int     main() {
  unsigned int num = 0xD2009010;

  printf("Value = 0x%X\n", num);
  write(1, "Binary: ", 8);
  for (int i = (sizeof(num) * 8); i >= 0; --i) {
    if (getBitValue(num, i))
      write(1, "1", 1);
    else
      write(1, "0", 1);
  }
  write(1, "\n", 1);
  printf("25th bit: %d\nBit at index 25 (26th): %d\n",
         getBitValue(num, 24),
         getBitValue(num, 25));
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to test the `25th` bit then `0x4000000` is not the right literal, depending on which bit you consider to be the starting bit then you are testing bit `26` or `27`.

Of course instead of using hand calculated literals, the easier way you be to use a bit shift, depending what what you consider the starting bit one of these should do what you need:

```
if( !(regVal & (1 << 24)) )
```

or

```
if( !(regVal & (1 << 25)) )
```

Comment: I should clarify what I meant: Bit number (first, second etc) doesn't have to be the same as the index. When doing bit shift it is _number_ _of_ _shifts_ so to get to the twentyfifth bit you have to shift 24 times. If you want to set the bit with index 25 then you shift 25 times.

Comment: @Jite Hmmm, not too clear or I am not getting it but I amended to take out the literals suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

If your code is exactly what you write, then `the bit is ...;` is not valid C. If that is the problem, use `puts("the bit is ...");`

About the condition, you should use `if (!(regVal & 0x1000000))`. That's the value of `1<<(25-1)`. (In my understandind 0x1 is first bit and so on)

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the address 0xD2009010 is that of the register you are reading, that the architecture you are using has memory mapped registers (and that you are probably writing a device driver, certainly not an application unless you are writing for vxWorks or DOS ....), then if you want to test bit 25 you should test for 0x2000000 (remember that bits start from 0, so each nibble goes up by 4: 0, 4, 8, etc, after 6 0s you are at bit 24 (this would be 0x1000000). You want 25, so this is 0x2000000.

Comment: whoops, you wrote 25th ... which is bit 24 .... ! abelenky is right and so is Shafik ... I am used at calling bits with their number not order (bit 0 instead of first etc. ...)

Comment: If you use numbers (like bit number 4) then bits do start at 0. This is a C convention. If you use order (first, second etc) then first is bit 0, second is bit 1 etc.

Comment: Yeah @user2568437, I wanted to stress out that the twentyfifth bit doesn't have to have index 25, which can be a bit confusing at times. Normally though the first bit has index 0 hence the twentyfifth bit has index 24.